# How to convert inner elements of a List[List[Int]] to tupleNs? (How to flatten polymorphic tupleNs)

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, extract, flatten

I want to convert multiple lists, each with a constant inner list size, that look like this:

```
    List(List(1, 2, 3), List(3, 4, 5))
    List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4))
```

to this:

```
    List((1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5))
    List((1, 2), (3, 4))
```

So, if `val q: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(3, 4, 5)`, one could attempt to try the following:

```
    q.map(_.collect { case a :: b => (a,b) })
```

This gives you something of the following form, for the 3 element list example:

```
    List((1, List(2, 3)), (3, List(4, 5)))
```

I cannot flatten the tuples because they contain two types: Int and List[Int], so I cannot turn `(1, List(2,3))` into `(1,2,3)` as desired.

So, how can I extend the flatten function to do this, or is there a better way to accomplish this in scala? Could scalaz help at all?

**tl;dr**: How can I turn inner lists of a list into tuples? (Possible generalized question: How to flatten polymorphic tupleNs?)

Comment: Is something wrong with `List(List(1,2,3)) map { case List(a,b,c) => (a,b,c)}`? A general is difficult because at compile time the length of a list is not known. Maybe you can use shapeless' `HList`

Comment: It might be possible to do something interesting with shapeless, but whether it's worth it or not (relative to @sschaef's suggestion above) very much depends on what you want to do with the result and whether or not you really do need polymorphism over arity. So could you show us some context?

Comment: You're right. I thought this was interesting and there might be an easy way but I guess not. I'm not even sure why I wanted tuples in the first place instead of the logical choice, lists. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use implicits to do something of the like:

```
trait TupOps[T,I] {
  val size: Int
  def fromList(vals: List[I]): T
}

def list2tup[T,I](vals: List[List[I]])(implicit to: TupOps[T,I]) = {
  if (!vals.forall(_.size == to.size)) sys.error("wrong list size")
  else vals.map(to.fromList _)
}

implicit def tup2ops[I] = new TupOps[(I,I),I] {
  val size = 2
  def fromList(v: List[I]) = (v(0), v(1))
}

implicit def tup3ops[I] = new TupOps[(I,I,I),I] {
  val size = 3
  def fromList(v: List[I]) = (v(0), v(1), v(2))
}
```

Invoke like this:

```
list2tup[(Int,Int),Int](List(List(1,2),List(2,3)))
```

But this is not necessarily nicer, especially because you have to write the `Int` a second time, which is IMHO rather a syntax limitation, since you cannot give one type and tell the compiler to infer the other.

**UPDATE**

It looks almost nicer if you pass in the implicit explicitly:

```
list2tup(List(List(1,2),List(2,3)))(tup2ops)
```